# How to add decode inside of the WHERE condition?

Tags: sql

The something inside of the decode would like to add another Condition? For example:

```
where decode (id, 'A', name not in ('B'), name not in('C')
```

So please give a solution...

Comment: Not clear. Please add an example - sample data and requested results. Also, are you using Oracle?

Comment: yes ji..  i would like to add notin condition inside of a decode.

select count(name) from  tablename1,tablename2  
where  decode (name, 'xxx',   empid in ('1'), empid not in('2') and tablename colid1=tablename2 id2;

Comment: Roleid more than 5 is here,, based upon roleid i want a count of emp.

select roleid,count(emp) ,location from tablename1 where decode (location,'1',roleid not in('role1'), roleid not in ('role2');


if location 1 is there i want a count of 5, else i want a count of 2..

Comment: Edwin, this make no sense. Please put the code aside and give an example using data, not code.

Comment: Dudu not in condition is inside of a decode is possible or not??

Comment: No. You are trying to force an invalid solution instead of asking a simple question.

Comment: column1    column2  column3

data1        xdata1     ydata1
data1        xdata2     ydata2
data1        xdata3     ydata3
data2        xdata4     ydata4

i want a result : count of data 1 and data2. the same time  check the condition of if data 1 is there ,column2 !=xdata4  and data2 is there column2=xdata4;

Comment: Please put it in the question and delete the comment

Comment: Ok dudu.. send a solution to me..

Comment: You didn't put the example in the question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change in something like this, without having to use a decode

```
   where (id='A' and name not in ('B')) or name not in ('C')
```

Comment: where is your commandbox and why don't you make simply copy and paste of the where ????